# Sheaf cohomology of long exact sequence of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety and $F_1,...,F_n$ be a collection of coherent sheaves on $X$. Suppose we have a long exact sequence

$$0\to F_n\to F_{n-1}\to...\to F_1\to0.$$

Knowing all sheaf cohomologies $H^i(X, F_{j})$, $j=2,...,n$, how could I compute $H^i(X, F_{1})$?

Comment: Try the hypercohomology spectral sequence.

Comment: Or a more elementary way of saying effectively the same thing: break down the long exact sequence into short ones. But in both cases, you're going to have to compute not just the cohomologies $H^i(X,\mathscr F_j)$, but also the maps between them (for fixed $i$ and varying $j$).